# Assigning specific colors to and ordered factor in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, boxplot, factors

I'm trying to assign specific colors to my boxplot/jitter plot but the scale_fill_manual and scale_colour_manual functions don't seem to be working.

When I execute this code, all points on the graph remain black:

```
DR_Ranges <-ggplot(data=Temp, aes(x=DRLevel, y=Range)) +
                   geom_jitter(size=1.2) +
                   geom_boxplot(size=1.2, alpha=0.5)

DR_Ranges + scale_fill_manual(values=c("Low"="Green", 
                                       "Moderate"="Yellow", 
                                       "Considerable"="Orange", 
                                       "High"="Red", 
                                       "Extreme"="Black"))
```

Comment: You haven't mapped the `fill` aesthetic to your data, do you need `aes(x=DRLevel, y=Range, fill = DRLevel)`?

Comment: In addition, you also need to use hexadecimal codes for colour values or built in colour names: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf. And the right aesthetic for points is `colour`, not `fill` I believe

Comment: Hi Callum, thanks for your input. I think fill = is used in the aes function if you don't want to manually select the colours of each level, but I do. Unfortunately I've used the scale_colour_manual function but that also didn't work

Comment: Nope, callum is right, you need to specify the fill argument in the `aes` function, then you can modify the colours manually. If you want to use scale_colour_manual then you need to specify `colour = variable` in the `aes` bit at them top